# Choosing the correct architecture for intel core i3-7100U processor

Tags: system-installation, architecture

I want to install Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 on a laptop with an intel core i3-7100U processor.  What architecture do I choose? According to the [installation guide page](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/) the choices are:

1. amd64 (AMD64 & Intel EM64T)
2. armhf (32-bit hard-float ARMv7)
3. arm64 (64-bit ARM)
4. i386 (Intel 32-bit PC)
5. powerpc (IBM/Motorola PowerPC)
6. ppc64el (PowerPC 64-bit Little-endian)
7. s390x (IBM System z)

Answer (score 23):

Every main-series (so the kind you'd find in your average computer) Intel processor is based off of the 8086 standard, as opposed to ARM or PowerPC. Meaning, our only two choices here will be `amd64` and `i386`.

Now, the difference between these is whether we want 64-bit support or not. The *vast* majority of modern computers now have 64-bit support, so we'd usually almost always want to choose `amd64`. There are very specific reasons to choose `i386`, but almost none of them apply to the standard home user (for example, `i386` will limit the number and type of applications you can run, and will cap you at 4GB of RAM).

However, just for the sake of completeness, let's check the [ARK page](https://ark.intel.com/products/95442/Intel-Core-i3-7100U-Processor-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz) for your processor. If we look at it, we can see that this processor is **Intel-64 supported**, meaning we can run the 64-bit OS (`amd64`).

The other architectures are rarely used in desktop computers, so we can usually ignore them. But, as we've already gone down the road of completeness:

- **`armhf`**: This is known as [ARMv7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#32-bit_architecture), and has been (in most cases) deprecated in favor of the new ARMv8 spec. This is primarily used in mobile/SoC-type devices, such as phones or IoT devices like your smart fridge or a Raspberry Pi.
- **`arm64`**: ARM64 (also known as [ARMv8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#ARMv8-A) or `aarch64`) is the next generation of ARM processors that support a full 64-bit instruction set. It is still primarily used in mobile and SoC applications, but it is slowly starting to breach the "full" computer environment, especially as it's very power-light and an open spec.
- **`powerpc`**: [PowerPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) is a very old processor architecture created by IBM and Motorola. It was famously used in older Apple computers. Currently, the primary use of PowerPC is in the realm of enterprise-grade applications and servers. However, some people will still use old PowerPC computers (e.g. old Macs) for lightweight servers or computers.
- **`ppc64el`**: PowerPC's original spec did not support the 64-bit instruction set (though was later added in the PowerPC 620 processor), which was critical for enterprise applications dealing with large amounts of data. As such, `ppc64el` was created for use by enterprise servers.
- **`s390x`**: [IBM System Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_z) is very rarely used outside of heavy datacenters. It describes a processor architecture used by IBM's mainframe line of servers. Finding a home computer running this architecture would be impossible.

**TL;DR**: If you have a reasonably modern computer and don't know what to install, use `amd64`.

Comment: +1 for a very complete and broadly useful answer.

Comment: Thank You for the clear and detailed answer!  I'll be choosing 64-bit support and now know which choice to make.  I especially like the link to the ARK page for my processor and the explanations about each type of architecture in the list.

Comment: The main reason to use `i386` on a 64-bit computer is if the computer will never have more than about 3GB of RAM installed.  `i386` is a bit more memory-efficient than `amd64`, so you'll make better use of the limited amount of RAM available.

Comment: The last PowerPC Macs are recent enough that they might still be useful (i.e. able to run a modern web browser, or at least be a file server), so PPC Linux has potential current uses other than enterprise systems and HPC clusters.  I think the wording in that bullet point could use a tweak to make it clear that you're talking about newly-sold PPC only being found in those systems.

Comment: @Mark: i386 Linux can take advantage of much more than 3 or 4GB of RAM, it's just less efficient (because the kernel can't have it all mapped at the same time and has to use PAE).  And no single process can map more than 3GB.  But you could have two separate processes each using 3GB of RAM (without either one paging to disk).  Since Chrome (the web browser) uses a separate process for each tab, there's definitely a real use-case here.

Comment: But unlike PowerPC64 or MIPS64, AMD64 adds more registers, uses a more efficient calling convention, and has RIP-relative addressing for efficient PIC code (all dynamic libraries, and ASLR executables).  So it's much more than just being able to use more memory, which is why running in AMD64 mode is often faster than i386 for the same program even when virtual address space limitations aren't a factor.  (If x32 ever catches on (32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode), we'll have the best of both worlds: all the advantages of amd64 with the cache footprint savings for pointer-heavy data structures.)

Comment: "Every Intel processor"... currently, as long as you discount the Itaniums and the ARMs they made in the past, and the ARMs that they will soon be making again :) Which is to say, I know what you mean, but "every Intel desktop processor and most of the server ones that you've heard of" is closer to the truth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install 64 bit operating system then install amd64.
If you want to install 32 bit operating system then install i386.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that `i386` architecture still has its uses, even if the CPU supports x64.

1. It indeed can use more than 4 GB of memory using PAE, the limit related to pointer size applies to individual processes, not the whole system.
2. If you ever want to run 32-bit code on your machine, you'll have to install all runtime libraries twice (in 32 and 64 bit versions), which may count if you have an SSD with limited available space. Two notable examples are Wine (which runs Win32 code in Linux) and Java (which is known to be slower and significantly more memory-hungry in its 64-bit incarnation).
3. Old code designed during 32-bit era (read: large parts of GNU/Linux) is somewhat more efficient when built for 32-bit architecture.

Of course, if you take this decision, you won't be able to run any 64-bit code (for example, Steam announced they are not supporting their 32-bit build anymore), so most users should stick to `amd64` nevertheless.